# How to Merge Array and Document Field in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this document in MongoDB

```
[
    {
        "locations": [5, 5],
        "id": "fff"
    },
    {
        "locations": [7, 7],
        "id": "aaa"
    },
    {
        "locations": [9, 9],
        "id": "ccc"
    }
]
```

And I want to merge the array field and string field into a field that contains a combination of them like this

```
{
    "device": [
        ["fff", 5, 5],
        ["aaa", 7, 7],
        ["ccc", 9, 9]
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to do this with aggregation? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`$concatArrays`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) to merge two fields and then [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to make it two dimensional array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "devices": { "$push": { "$concatArrays": [["$id"], "$locations"] } }
  }}
])
```

[**Output**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gmrQNIW9XyV)

```
[
  {
    "devices": [
      ["fff", 5, 5],
      ["aaa", 7, 7],
      ["ccc", 9, 9]
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Working great. I tried a approachment like directly `{ "$push": ["$id", "$locations"] }` but it turns there's one operator that I need to add. Thank you.